# Does anyone know how to solve problems on variable length arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of  (the number of variable-length arrays) and  (the number of queries). 
Each line of the subsequent lines contains a space-separated sequence in the format k a[i]0 a[i]1 … a[i]k-1 describing the -element array located at. 
Each of the subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of  (an index in the array ) and  (an index in the array referenced by ) for a query.

Output Format-
For each pair of and  values (i.e., for each query), print a single integer denoting the element located at an index of the array referenced by. There should be a total of lines of output.

Sample Input

2 2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3
0 1
1 3
Sample Output

5
9

Somebody has solved this problem by -

```
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
   int n,q; //n number of variable lenght arrays
   // q no of queries asked
    cin >>n >>q;
   int ** Vectors = new int *[n];//no of length of var. arrays
   int j;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        cin>>j;
        Vectors[i] = new int [j];
        for (int y=0;y<j;y++)
            cin>>Vectors[i][y];
    }
    int q1,q2;
    for (int i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        cin >>q1 >> q2;
        cout<<Vectors[q1][q2]<<endl;

     }

    return 0; 
}
```

Can somebody explain me this code? Or if anyone has a better approach to solve this problem. Then please explain it in detail.

Comment: a better approach would be `std::vector`, which already implement a big part of that for you,

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be hard to understand, that code is basically initializing dynamic 2D array at run time then inserting values to the 2D array and then accessing it by giving index:

```
int ** Vectors = new int *[n];//no of length of var. arrays
       int j;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   
            cin>>j;
            Vectors[i] = new int [j]; // initialzing inner array.. consider it as 2D array with n rows and j columns
            for (int y=0;y<j;y++)
                cin>>Vectors[i][y]; // insert element at specified index
        }

cout<<Vectors[q1][q2]<<endl; // access element from 2D array
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to use is a Matrix class. 
Using

```
vector<vector<int>>
```

should do it.

Alternatively the snipet code should be refactored into a Matrix class with a constructor and a destructor.
The example you give present a memory leak since the allocated memory is not freed.